# Should my CMake imported targets have dependencies?

Tags: cmake

Is there a proper and clean way to add dependencies to an `IMPORTED` target in CMake (v3.17)?

I'm using `CommonAPI-DBus`, which does install a `CommonAPI-DBusConfig.cmake` file but doesn't define "useful" targets, so I want to wrap it with my own target.  My preferred name is `CommonAPI::DBus` (because my ideal setup would have `DBus` as one of many components in the `CommonAPI` namespace), and because of the `::` it has to be an imported target, fine.

`CommonAPI-DBus` depends on DBus-1, which isn't implicitly imported anywhere, so I want my target to also bring in DBus-1 (which I can get with `find_package(DBus-1)`), and that's where I run into problems.

I see two options:

**1) Copy the `dbus-1` properties to my target:**

The `DBus-1` package creates a `dbus-1` target, so I can set up my target like:

```
 if(NOT TARGET CommonAPI::DBus)
  add_library(CommonAPI::DBus INTERFACE IMPORTED)
  set_target_properties(CommonAPI::DBus PROPERTIES
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${COMMONAPI_DBUS_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
    INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES      "${CommonAPI_DBus_LIBRARY}"
  )

  foreach(var IN ITEMS INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)
    get_target_property(tmp dbus-1 ${var})
    if(tmp)
      message("Coping ${var} from dbus-1: ${tmp}")
      set_property(TARGET CommonAPI::DBus APPEND PROPERTY ${var} ";${tmp}")
    endif()
  endforeach()

  # Get the dbus-1 library
  get_target_property(tmp dbus-1 IMPORTED_LOCATION)
  set_property(TARGET CommonAPI::DBus APPEND PROPERTY INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES ${tmp})
  unset(tmp)
endif()
```

But that's pretty ugly, and a lot of code to maintain

**2) Ignore the `dbus-1` target and use the exported variables**

`find_package(dbus-1)` does export `DBus1_INCLUDE_DIR` and `DBus1_LIBRARY`, *etc*.  I could simply use these properties, however this feels like an "old" way of using CMake.  In my opinion the main advantage of CMake is the ability to define targets which dictate own interface and encapsulate their setup logic, rather than downstream artifacts using private variables from its setup script.

I suppose what I want is an `INTERFACE` target that uses `::` to make it clear that I'm using a namespace.

Comment: Is there anything bad with `target_link_libraries(CommonAPI::DBus INTERFACE dbus-1)`?

Comment: `::` can only be used with `IMPORTED` targets, which doesn't allow `target_link_libraries`.  _e.g._ if I remove the `IMPORTED`, I get the error `The target name "CommonAPI::DBus" is reserved or not valid for certain`.  If I try `target_link_libraries` on the `IMPORTED` target, I get the error `INTERFACE library can only be used with the INTERFACE keyword of target_link_libraries`

Comment: Wjhat about `add_library(common_api_dbus INTERFACE)` with `add_library(CommonAPI::DBus ALIAS common_api_dbus)`? Side note: I really do not understand the need for `::` in name - you seem to be writing an `INTERFACE` target, not an `IMPORTED`, so you just shouldn't use `::`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Actually, while I swear I tested that, it does sort of work.  Sort of because when I do that, my code builds, but the weird part is (and why I thought it didn't work) was that when I then do `get_target_property` on my target, I don't see anything from the dbus-1 target in either `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` or `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`.. But it clearly does work (if I remove it, it breaks, when I add it, it works).  Am I just debugging my reading the wrong properties?  Most of them seem to be "not whitelisted" (not totally sure what that means)

Comment: @KamilCuk For the namespace, I suppose that was one of my questions, "_SHOULD_" I even be doing this?  My desire for a namespace is because DBus is one of a couple different transport/middleware libraries, so I thought it would be best to use a namespace to link against `CommonAPI::Dbus`, or `CommonAPI::SOMEIP`, and other components like `CommonAPI::Core`.  From a code perspective it seems like a clean interface, but maybe I'm thinking about this wrong?

Comment: Hmm, never thought about using an ALIAS like that, I can give that a try

Comment: As far as I remember, you may achieve INTERFACE linking by simply appending to `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES`. In your code you append just `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property of `dbus-1`, but you may add here `dbus-1` as a **whole target**, so copying `dbus-1` properties won't be needed. Also, constraints of  `target_link_libraries` command are evolved with newer CMake versions. Could you specify (in the question post) which version of CMake do you use?

Comment: @Tsyvarev When I print out the properties,  I do simply see "dbus-1", but stuff seems to work.  I think I'm simply debugging my targets wrong. :(  I did add the CMake version (3.17) to the question though.  I do like KamilCuk alias solution, it seems to give me an interface target and a target that appears to be in a namespace.  Issue with CMake is that there are many ways to accomplish something, but it's hard to know the "right" way :)

Comment: No need to replicate properties of `dbus-1` in your `CommonAPI::DBus` target. The only purpose of your target is working when one links with it (using `target_link_libraries`). As for using the namespace for your target: If `dbus-1` is an IMPORTED target (as far as I understand, this is true since it is created with `find_package(Dbus-1)`, then your wrapper target could perfectly mimic IMPORTED behavior, including the namespace.